# tableView with custom cells and delay

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableView with custom cells when I switch to the first time there is a delay, after searching for a problem, I found out that displaying a photo is the reason I was looking for a problem, but nothing helped. I tried to make the transition in Main Queue

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TVCellMenu else { return UITableViewCell()}
        let data = category[indexPath.row]
        cell.title.text = data.name

        //image is reason

        let image = UIImage(named: data.image_name ?? "", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)
        cell.ImageView.image = image

        return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menu") as! VCMenu
        vc.isCategory = false
        vc.subCategory = self.category[indexPath.row].subCategory
        vc.position = self.category[indexPath.row].position
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: which  transition in Main Queue ? in didSelectRowAt ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes in didSelectRowAt

Answer (score 0):

when loading the image is to slow, you should consider to load it async.

for example:

add a function to TVCellMenu:

```
func loadImage(imageName: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName ?? "", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)
        self.ImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

then (instead of setting the image directly) just call the function in cellForRowAt:

```
    cell.loadImage(imageName: data.image_name ?? ""); 

    return cell
```